# Error con notifyItemInserted() al enviar un mensaje Android Studio : Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy haciendo una app de un chat sencillo, al momento de escribir un mensaje y mostrarlo en pantalla la app se detiene, sospecho que el error esta en notifyItemInserted() y quisiera saber si estoy haciendo mal uso de la función o si existe otra forma de hacer que los mensajes se muestren en pantalla.

Gracias por su ayuda!!

```
public class AdapterMensajes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HolderMensaje> {

        private List<Mensaje> listMensaje = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context c;

        public AdapterMensajes(Context c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void addMensaje(Mensaje m){
            listMensaje.add(m);
            notifyItemInserted(listMensaje.size());
        }
```

Este es el error mostrado en el LogCat:

> 09-06 15:27:39.896 6174-6174/vdachi.startalking E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: vdachi.startalking, PID: 6174
>       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class
>   android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
>       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

Comment: el error no tiene que ver con  notifyItemInserted() , en realidad estas definiendo en tu layout una clase que no existe en el SDK, agrega tu layout donde se encuentra CircleImageView .

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: revisa mi respuesta y me comentas resultados, no uses "android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView" , saludos!  @VDachi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas tratando de inflar una clase que no existe en el SDK... bueno en este caso existe pero NO se puede instanciar:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_androide" />
```

Te sugiero usar otra opción como https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView ,

ejemplo:

```
      <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/CircleImageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/androide" />
```

agregando la dependencia dentro de tu `/app/build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
  ...
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa otras opciones :

https://android.jlelse.eu/circular-imageview-nightmare-for-beginners-822c4137e629

Comment: Utilice el ejemplo inmediato que me dejarte y ya funciona correctamente

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y la verdad también me resolviste la duda de a donde se registraban los error, soy novato en el IDE y el lenguaje.

Saludos

Comment: Un placer ayudarte @VDachi, recuerda que es esencial utilizar el LogCat para desarrollo Android, ya que puedes determinar y resolver un problema en segundos, de otra forma tardarías incluso días tratando de encontrar el problema. No olvides revisar [tour], saludos!.